# If-then condition in JSON Schema isn't working

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Following is the jsonSchema.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "array",
  "items": [
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "isMerchant": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "isAgent": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "cashLoan": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "personalDetail": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "contact": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "email": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "mobile": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "area": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "state": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "required": ["state"]}
      },
      "required": ["isMerchant","cashLoan","contact"],
      "allOf": [
        {
          "if": {
            "properties": {
              "isMerchant": {"enum": [true]}
            }
          },
          "then": {
            "required": [ "isAgent","email","mobile"]
          }
        },
        {
          "if": {
            "properties": {
              "cashLoan": {"enum": [true]}
            }
          },
          "then": {
            "required": ["personalDetail"]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Expectation is to validate the corresponding JSON data with this JSON schema. where conditions are as follows -

1. If 'isMerchant' = true then the params 'isAgent', 'email', 'mobile' should be present in the json file.
2. If 'cashLoan' = true then param 'personalDetail' should be present.

Answer (score 0):

With draft 2020-12, the type of the `items` keyword can only be `object` or `boolean`.

[image]

Comment: It was draft-07. updated the query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `"requires": [...]` to your `if` conditions, because the `properties` keyword will evaluate to true if the property is not present at all, therefore you are entering the `then` conditionals when you don't intend to.